# Is there an NP-hard problem that is polynomially reducible to its complement, and whose complement is polynomially reducible to the problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

I suppose that this statement is true if NP equals with coNP, otherwise not, but I don't know how can I prove that.

Answer (score 2):

Take any NP-hard problem $A \subseteq \{0,1\}^*$. Now let $\langle A, \overline{A}\rangle := \{0w \mid w \in A\} \cup \{1w \mid w \notin A\}$. Clearly, $A$ is polytime reducible to $\langle A, \overline{A}\rangle$ via $w \mapsto 0w$, thus $\langle A, \overline{A}\rangle$ inherits being NP-hard from $A$. Also,  $\langle A, \overline{A}\rangle$ is polytime equivalent to its own complement, namely by the map that just flips the first bit.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Can it be proven formally?

Comment: @knorbika Sure. Pick whatever formal proof system you want to use, and write it down. For usual standards of rigour, my answer already contains everything.

Comment: Is it true for all NP-hard problems?

Comment: @knorbika, this site is not intended for interactive back-and-forth.  Please don't use the comments to ask follow-up questions.  Instead, you can use the 'Ask Question' button if you have a new question.  Make sure to provide full context, including the motivation for the question, and what progress you've made and summarize what you've found so far in your search/research.

Comment: @knorbika the answer says `Take any NP-hard problem`, therefore yes, and the answer is complete.